# obtener tamaño de un archivo en ftp c#

Tags: c#, ftp, rutas, file

Tengo que obtener el tamaño de un archivo de ftp. Me aparece este error

> ```
> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Net.FileWebRequest' to type 
> 'System.Net.FtpWebRequest'
> ```

en la línea que creo el objeto FtpWebRequest. Os dejo el código que tengo de momento:

```
public static long FtpGetFileSize(string uri, string username, string password)
{
        // Get the object used to communicate with the server

        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.GetFileSize;

        // Get network credentials.
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);

        try
        {
            using (FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                // Return the size.
                Console.WriteLine("El tamaño del archivo es {0}",response.ContentLength);
                return response.ContentLength;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // If the file doesn't exist, return -1
            // Otherwise rethrow the error
            if (ex.Message.Contains("File unavailable")) return -1;
            throw;
        }                           
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No puedes convertir el `WebRequest` a `FtpWebRequest`. El problema es que en tu parámetro `uri` le debes estar pasando un path local, y por ello te aparece esa excepción. Debes asegurarte de que el parámetro que le pasas en `uri` sea una dirección ftp válida.

Comment: me sigue apareciendo el mismo error con este cambio

Comment: es en la misma línea

Comment: @LopezAi suponiendo que sea una aplicación winforms, y que tengas `using System.Net` en tu código, no es posible. Mira en [este fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/oXbUGu) cómo funciona perfectamente.

Comment: @Pikoh En la [página de microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest(v=vs.110).aspx) el ejemplo que muestran es el que tiene el OP en el código, y se supone que debería ir bien. Debe de estar en otro lugar el error.

Comment: @Marc tienes razón. El error es por lo que le pasa en `uri` casi seguro.

Comment: @LopezAi mira la edición de mi respuesta. Tu problema debe ser lo que le estás pasando en `uri`

Comment: @Pikoh Correcto, el error debe ir por allí, ya que el código aparentemente está bien.

Comment: ya lo he corregido, el error estaba en como le pasaba el parámetro, que no lo estaba haciendo poniendo la dirección del server ftp, sino pasándole el directorio local. Gracias por la ayuda!